# How to publish a package from Visual Studio to azure artifacts

Tags: azure, visual-studio, nuget, azure-artifacts

I am looking for a way to publish a package from visual studio to azure artifact's feed. I am able to do that using cli and azure pipeline, but now I am looking for a way to do that from visual studio 2022.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

> How to publish a package from Visual Studio to azure artifacts

I am afraid there is no out of box way publish a package from Visual Studio to azure artifact feed.

We have to do this via cli and azure pipeline.

If you still want to do this by Visual Studio, you could add a MSBuild customer task in the project file to invoke the cli to publish packge:

```
<Target Name="PublishMyPackage" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="<give your command here>" />
</Target>
```